# Amazon CDC replication with Mysql auora to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, replication

I need Mysql auora to SQL Server data replication with Amazon RDS. I am not able to see any document which help me for this.

Steps for creating Mysql auora to SQL Server

Step 1: I created a Mysql RDS on Amazon account.

Step 2:

I need to enable CDC(change data capture) into mysql server, but I am not able to find any document which help me to enable the CDC (Mysql server)

Please help me on this,

Thanks

Aman middha

Comment: **CDC** is a feature of Microsoft **SQL Server** - not of "MySQL" (which you keep referring to in your question)

Comment: ok , Thanks for reply ,I created Mysql auora RDS into amazon then i also connected the End Points of both database(Myserver(Source) and sql server(destination)) with amazon login. then you know want is the next step.

Comment: Sql server to mysql data replication is working fine for me